# How can I add new rows without deleting the previous ones using openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I'm new to python programming and I'm developing code that writes the value of a known variable into an excel sheet. This variable is the result of the python code that I developed. It updates its value every time the code is executed so in the end of the code, I would like to save the variable to the excel file.

My problem is related to updating the excel: **when I write a new row, it deletes the previous rows**. I want to save all my results in that excel file, but I only manage to save the last result I get.

I have tried many things but none has given me what I wanted as a result.

I'm using python 2.7 with pandas but I was trying to write in the excel file with openpyxl.

**Question: How can I achieve saving rows to excel without deleting the previous rows?**

Comment: The best would be, if you can provide some code showing what that creates for you. Usually you will receive the answer where somebody will modify your code with the information what you could do different way.

Comment: You could load the excel sheet using the pandas function pd.read_excel() in a dataframe called results and add your new result to it. Then save that dataframe. This way you will keep all your previous results

Comment: You should always include some code showing what you're trying to do and ask specific questions about it.